# Wampserver is not displaying images or videos. Permission issue?

Tags: php, html, wamp

I have a question regarding PHP and Wampserver.

If one were to have a Wampserver, use PHP to scan a certain folder for all movie files and make it so all of the files loads up fully playable. Would this be possible?
I have tried doing this with other files like images and what not, but the content is not loading on the localserver.(I can see that the files did get scanned and they are there, but they are not being shown, only their names).
Permission issue?
The Wampserver and the movie folder are on different drives(I do not want to move all my movies into the www folder).

Apologies in advance for my English and stupidity.

```
<?php
$folder = "A:/images/";

$files = scandir($folder);
$allowedExtensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "mp4", "webm");
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExtensions)) {
        if (in_array(strtolower($extension), array("mp4", "webm"))) {
            echo '<video controls>';
            echo '<source src="' . $folder . '/' . $file . '" type="video/' . $extension . '">';
            echo 'Your browser does not support the video tag.';
            echo '</video>';
        } else {
            echo '<img src="' . $folder . '/' . $file . '" alt="' . $file . '">';
        }
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Movies</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="movies">
    <?php include 'scandir.php'; ?>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pls edit your question to include your code

Comment: _"The Wampserver and the movie folder are on different drives(I do not want to move all my movies into the www folder)"_ - you are not automatically allowed HTTP access all over the file system. You should probably set up an [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) via the server or vhost confiuration.

Comment: In most cases there is no need to guess. File system functions in PHP have special return values on error that you can check, and the older ones often throw warnings. Make sure you have configured PHP to display errors in your development box.

Comment: Use your browser's Developer Tools to debug what's happening when you load these files into the browser and try to play them. Any console errors? Unexpected network errors (e.g. HTTP requests returning 404 or 403 or that kind of thing)? We don't know, we can't see your environment. So instead of asking us whether it's a permissions issue, you need to ask your computer. Or maybe it's some other problem - again we don't know because you didn't provide a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. We can't fix vague/unspecified error in invisible code (which should not be surprising, really)! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample.  You've put `<source src="' . $folder` ...but `$folder` is `"A:/images/"`. The `src` in a HTML element needs to be a **URL** accessible via HTTP/HTTPS - not a filesystem path.